# Return common columns on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've currently got two rows of a dataframe that look like this:

```
user_id    movieA    movieB    movieC    movieD
512A        0.0       1.0       2.0        1.0
AB72        1.0       2.0       0.0        3.0
```

and I'd like to return a list that represents columns where both the users have rated a film above `0.0`. I.e. for the above example I'd ideally get a list that looks like `[movieB, movieD]`.

Is this even possible? I had a look through the functions available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_functions.html), but I'm not sure how to combine them for this result.

Comment: `s=df.iloc[:,1:].gt(0).all(); s[s].index`?

Comment: Hi - can you explain this a little further? I'm not sure that I follow the logic :)

Comment: The pandas [indexing and selecting data user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) might be more useful than just clicking through individual functions or methods

Comment: Do have some piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = df.set_index("user_id")
df.columns[df.gt(0).all(axis=0)].tolist()
```

We first set `user_id` as the index to have a clear notation i.e. not having to type `df.iloc[:, 1:]` instead of `df` on the other line. Then we check where the dataframe has values greater than 0 (`gt(0)`) and then check for which columns their entries are all greater than 0 (`all(axis=0)`). Then we use this as a mask over the columns of the df and lastly convert it `tolist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
data = data[data > 0.0] # Initial condition: all rates above zero
data = data.dropna(axis=1) # Drop all columns that not pass the initial condition
filt_cols = data.columns.tolist() # Get the name cols with non zero value.
```